# How to make a Bootstrap page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I must make a webpage using Bootstrap.

These are the requirements:

> 1 page in bootstrap. We have attached a handmade sketch. The page will have a list. In each list, there will be a title, 8 text fields in the group of 2 divided into 4 parts.
>
> For example, FirstName: Oracle(2 fields), LastName: Maven (2 fields), and so on, an image slider, which can have minimum 1 and maximum 3 images in it. We can view the image on a big scale and zoom in zoom out the image. Below the slider will be Approve and Reject button which will be visible ONLY at the last Image. The right side of the section will contain 11 Input fields along with the labels. all are optional. Below the 11 fields will be a submit button. This will repeat like a list.

This is the sketch:

[image]

I don't understand how to do the lists.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: You can start with one of the [templates](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/) and then visit the docs on how to populate it with things. Note that Bootstrap does make layout stuff easier (both in implementation and testing terms) but knowing what thing to use where needs a bit of reading.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't use Bootstrap and don't know how it's function better download some tool for making bootstrap sites or if you are familiar download a template.

Take a look on Pingendo, it's a drag and drop desktop application (you also have web) and just pick which element you want and drop it on the page...